# Passing firebase data by intent causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, google-cloud-firestore

My data is from Firebase cloud Firestore, it doesn't contain a slash "/" because every solution to this problem about this always tell me to use `.replace("/","-")`. The ID is a generic ID from Firebase "cHkncpz6RVHv4ITFlICr"

**HomePageAdapter.java**

```
Intent passID = new Intent(itemView.getContext(),Destination.class);
passID.putExtra("ID", destinationID);
itemView.getContext().startActivity(passID);
```

**Destination.java**

```
ID = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
firebaseFirestore.collection("DESTINATION").document(ID) <----- this line throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but DESTINATIONS has 1
```

What I tried so far are:

1. Replacing the String ID into `ID = "cHkncpz6RVHv4ITFlICr";` and of course the app works.
2. Tracked if the ID is blank, it was not because the LOG says the ID is "cHkncpz6RVHv4ITFlICr".

```
Log.d("ID", destinationID);
```

returns

```
D/ID: cHkncpz6RVHv4ITFlICr
```

3. Replaced the extra in Intent `passID.putExtra("ID", "cHkncpz6RVHv4ITFlICr");` the app didn't work.

So what I conclude is the intent is causing this exception. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Log `ID` in Destination.java just before you pass it to Firestore.  It is almost certainly an empty string.

Comment: @DougStevenson oh yeah that's right. Now for the question is why I don't get the data from Intent?

Comment: I suggest editing the question to state the new problem and what you've done to debug this.  You'll have to show more code.